# opendj server status started but displaying open connections 0

Tags: opendj

I am new to opendj, When I try to start opendj server, getting status as server is started but open connections are "0".could any one please help me how to fix this issue
I am using linux ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an OpenDJ is started, it has no opened connection to it, unless there are client applications that are connected to it and sending LDAP operations.
So, you have started the server, and the status command tells you it's started and working... I don't think there's anything to fix.
May be it you start some client application, you will see that there could be some opened connections.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.Here I've another Q's Some times when I start server getting timeout error "The timeout of '200' seconds to start the server has been reached.  You can
use the argument '--timeout' to increase this timeout" Could you please let me know why am getting this error and how can i fix it?

Comment: Either the server fails to start due to an error (and that error would appear in the logs/errors file, or the system lacks resources to start the server (memory or cpu cycles).
You might want to try to start the server with start-ds -N to see if there is any specific error message.